# Error in QGIS - Can't export map as JPG

Tags: qgis, raster

I have few rasters, they are on WGS84 4326, I want to save them as image and then to upload the image and that it will appear on the correct location.
for some reson, whenever I try to export the rasters as image, and the I try to upload it as raster it uploaded it but it doesn't display.

I tried also to merge all the rasters but all I got was black line  like this-
[image: this is what I got from merging the rasters]

I'm afraid it may happen because some  rasters overlap a little on the edges , which is not problematic for my project but  maybe problematic for QGIS?

Comment: have you set the nodata value for the rasters? that could be the cause of the black line.

Comment: what do you mean no data value?

Comment: rasters have a value that signals to QGIS that the pixel is invalid or missing data. This is common if your raster is rotated with respect to the coordinate system and has a black 'border' around it to make it square. You can check the nodata value using gdalinfo:
 `gdalinfo <name of raster> ` https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/processing/no_data.html